# Will image quality be better if I covert VGA to DVI-D

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

The current situation is this:

- CPU: only VGA port
- 2 monitors: VGA and DVI-D (dual link)
- Available cables: DVI-D (single link), VGA
- On board graphics

I'm thinking about buying a VGA-to-DVI adapter (male-to-female, respectively) and a DVI splitter. I then can hook the cables on the splitter monitors. Will it make the image quality significantly better? If not then I may use VGA cable and only need to buy a VGA splitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VGA signal is an analog signal an in comparison to DVI is often times perceived as of poorer quality. Converting that signal to something else won't fix it. You could try this approach if you have excessively long cables as usually a DVI cable has less loss of quality per length unit.

If you do have the option try to switch to DVI-D which should improve the quality. Actually as your setup already includes a display which is using DVI you should be able to notice the difference.

Maybe describe the issue your experience which makes you consider this option to get some more helpful information.

Comment: This situation is because I bought a CPU and two monitors from different sources. Cable lengths are OK. I haven't encountered a problem since I in fact haven't been able to set up the dual monitors yet. But I feel a bit unclear as you say converting VGA to, say, DVI won't likely improve the quality. Then you suggest to switch to DVI-D, which I understand for my setup means using a VGA-to-DVI adapter and then a DVI splitter.

Comment: `Available cables: DVI-D (single link), VGA` my assumption was that it means that you have one DVI port and one VGA port available on your board/card. As such you could drive one display using VGA and one DVI. From your comment I guess the only connection that's available to you is a VGA port?

Comment: Yes, currently my available option is only VGA port (on CPU). Monitors do have both VGA and DVI-D ports, which is the reason for my question. Cables are somehow external, but just to note what I have in hand. Based on your and Kevin's comments, I think I'd rather go with a graphic card or VGA, instead of an intermediate, "compromising" solution, which in the end seems not to work as much.